# Tidying up my php loop

Tags: php

I've created a foreach loop and it seems to be doing two different loops, which is messing up the output.

How can I combine these so that they're on the same if statement and only printing the bootstrap div closing tags for all of it?

https://webdesignbelfast.com/psychic/

```
<div class="container home-section padding-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Available Readers Online Now!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <?php

        $psychiclist = simplexml_load_file('https://www.digitalselect-uk.com/psychic/xml/profiles');

        foreach ($psychiclist as $psychicinfo):
            $picture = $psychicinfo->picture;
            $status = $psychicinfo->status;
            $name = $psychicinfo->name;
            $pin = $psychicinfo->pin;

            if ($status == "Available") {
                $available = $status;
                echo "
        <div class='col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>
            <img height='100%' width='100%' src='", $picture, "'>
            <p class='status available'>", $available, "</p>
            <p class='name'>", $name, "</p>
            <p class='pin'>Pin: ", $pin, "</p>
        </div>
        ";
            }

            if ($status == "Available") {
                $counter++;
                if ($counter % 6 == 0) {
                    echo '</div><div class="row text-center">';
                }
            }

            if ($status == "Busy") {
                $busy = $status;
                echo "
        <div class='col-sm-2 col-xs-4'>
            <img height='100%' width='100%' src='", $picture, "'>
            <p class='status busy'>", $busy, "</p>
            <p class='name'>", $name, "</p>
            <p class='pin'>Pin: ", $pin, "</p>
        </div>
        ";
            }

            if ($status == "busy") {
                $counter++;
                if ($counter % 6 == 0) {
                    echo '</div><div class="row text-center">';
                }
            }
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your website link is horribly broken.

Comment: Oh sorry hang on!

Comment: Please learn about model view controller logic... The xml is your model. Your controller is what parses the data in it and puts it in single variables, and the view just renders the stuff, with just the variables and no logic or very little logic in it.

Comment: That's the link fixed now, okay let me google it

Comment: `comma` for string appending? How much is your experience? Use a `dot` for appending: `WRONG:` "Hello","World", `Corect:` "Hello"."World".

Comment: This is my first attempt im trying to learn it for this project.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Nope, that's perfectly valid, and even slightly more efficient: it passes multiple arguments to the `echo` statement, rather than concatenating them as one string. http://php.net/echo

Comment: You want to display 6 online readers at 1 row?

Comment: Yes 6 on one row, its working but the loop is running two different loops for closing it and it's confusing it

Comment: @Tschallacka MVC is far from the only way of structuring code, and over-engineering is just going to kill off all enthusiasm for a beginner trying a small project. Even if I was restructuring this code, I'd be tempted to say that `$psychiclist`, being a list of objects with known structure, would be a valid input for a view, although I know opinions vary on how "rich" view logic should be.

Comment: I know it's far from the only one, but it's best in my opinion to start out with a good set of basic boots, instead of starting on rags. You can even do mvc in one file, just do the data parsing before you do the output. I'm not saying he has to use objects to seperate the three strictly

Comment: Is the difference between `if ($status == "Busy") {` and `if ($status == "busy") {` in your real code? If so, I'm guessing that's your actual bug, and there's nothing wrong with the loop. **`==` is case sensitive**, so only one of those will match, never both.

Comment: Forget about the xml it's coming in the way I want it. It's the two if statements thats confusing the $counter++ for closing the rows.

Comment: @Tschallacka Then how would this code actually look any different? You'd move the line `$psychiclist = simplexml_load_file('https://www.digitalselect-uk.com/psychic/xml/profiles');` further up, but otherwise this code *is* the View code.

Comment: Everything works but I had to sort the available status and busy status into two if statements and two counters. So Im trying to do is combine then both so that this piece of code is only running once for the loop:

if ($status == "busy") {$counter++;
                  if ($counter % 6 == 0) {
                  echo '</div><div class="row text-center">';}
                }

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I've learnt something today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should provide you with the desired result.

First of all, the only difference is the status of the readers, and you're doing a different if statement only because they are busy because that affects a css class.

You can prevent that by just making a variable for the css class(basically the status to lowercase)

They you also implemented the logic for the rows. You don't need to do that. bootstrap(the css library you're using) will do that for you, responsively. It can't make it beautifully responsive if you force rows between it, which will act as hard line breaks.
Bootstrap will automatically wrap to the next line when needed. every 3 images on col-xs, every 6 images on col-md with your current column width assignments.

Also, to make the code a bit more manageable, and enable html highlighting in your editor, you can just add a 'stop php' tag `?>` to enable outputting of the html and then use the short echo tags to just echo the value of the variable
`<?= $somevariable ?>`

With this setup you come with a basic MVC(model view controller) setup. where the model is the simplexml object, the controller is the loop, where the variables are assigned, parsed and made proper, and the view, the html code with php short echo's.

Implementing all that we end up with:

```php
<div class="container home-section padding-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Available Readers Online Now!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <?php

        $psychiclist = simplexml_load_file('https://www.digitalselect-uk.com/psychic/xml/profiles');

        foreach ($psychiclist as $info):

            $picture = $info->picture;
            $status = $info->status;
            $name = $info->name;
            $pin = $info->pin;
            $cssclass = strtolower($status);
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                <img height="100%" width="100%" src="<?= $picture ?>">
                <p class="status <?= $cssclass ?>"><?= $available ?></p>
                <p class="name"><?= $name ?></p>
                <p class="pin">Pin: <?= $pin ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I pasted this and it's not displaying the xml. I also need to close bootstrap rows after 6 cols. Also display available first and busy, while putting the classes for available and busy on the status div.

Comment: The problem with my code is I coded and pasted the if statement twice for busy as well so it's counting the closing divs on a wrong number for bootstrap.

Comment: yes, but the 6 cols will differ when you are on mobile. because then you have forced them on a new line unaturally. let bootstrap do it. you already defined the widths. bootstrap will wrap it for you. it will wrap automatically to a new line. it will wrap to a new line every 3 psychics on a mobile(your col-xs statement). I also fixed the not working part, forgot to rename the overly long variable name pshychicinfo to info.

Comment: $cssclass = strtolower($status); is what I needed! Thanks!